# Is it possible to have multiple azure web sites running off a single reserved instance

Tags: azure

Microsoft recently released to preview Azure web sites. I had been hoping that this would allow us to host multiple web sites off a single reserved instance. While the management interface for the web sites allows you to define multiple host headers, from what I can gather these will point to the same website, i.e. you could browse to www.someurl.com and www.someurl.org and end up at the same web site rather than the 2 being separate sites on the same VM.

Does anyone know if my reading of things is correct and if it isn't (i.e. multiple sites can be hosted through the website feature) how you go about setting this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Once you are using Reserved Windows Azure Websites, for your website and you do have ability to run multiple website in it. The process to run multiple website will be exactly same as any other IIS web server where you create multiple website and depend on different hostheader you will route the traffic to specific physical folder.

Comment: Thanks sounds sensible. Do you know how to connect to the VM? There doesn't appear to be anything in the Azure GUI giving RDP details for a reserved web site instance.

Comment: During Preview, Windows Azure Websites (shared and reserved) don't have RDP access enabled. You can deploy your application either by FTP, GIT or from TFS directly.