# How to configure multiple host headers for one Azure WebSite reserved instance

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I know that you can support multiple host headers on an Azure WebSite reserved instance based on this question - [Is it possible to have multiple azure web sites running off a single reserved instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006428/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-azure-web-sites-running-off-a-single-reserved-in)

My question is how do you configure a reserved server to respond to the different host headers in Azure Websites? With a regular WebRole I know you edit the ServiceDefinition file, but my understanding was that it doesn't exist for Azure Websites.

Comment: Currently this feature is not available for web sites. Please use a web role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add multiple host headers for Windows Azure Reserve Websites you will need to add directly from portal in configure section as shown below:

[image]

In your code,  you will handle the hostheader based routing to specific section of content.

Comment: As of 9.17.2012 there is a new way to set up CNAMEs in [tag:azure-web-sites] you can find the [guidance on WindowsAzure.com](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/)