# Using dynamic domain mapping in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, mapping, dns, cname

I have SaaS web-site that allows users create online landing pages and need to be able to give them option to use own domains. I've read a lot here about using custom domain on Windows Azure, but it all says that I need to go to Preview portal and manually add domain in configuration after I set up CNAME for the domain. Right now my Azure address is like

my-site.azurewebsites.net

and looks like www.my-site.com having CNAME record my-site.azurewebsites.net only gets 404 page. I've found here answer that I need manually add www.my-site.com to domain list in Azure preview portal. But what if I need for domains www.my-site1.com...www.my-siteN.com to be added  with changed CNAME record dynamically? It is impossible to manually add record for every domain. Is it possible to omit manual domain addition to Azure portal and have clients use their domains changing only CNAME and my code on Azure would analyze host and provides appropriate content?

Michael

Comment: Do you have a reserved instance? CNAMEs are currently only supported in reserved instances.

Comment: Yes. The problem is covered in this answer where it is said that I need manually add domains to Azure even after changing CNAME of the domains: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530507/how-to-configure-multiple-host-headers-for-one-azure-website-reserved-instance#)

Comment: The thing is there is need for clients to be able to add domains on their own. They will change CNAME and it should work, but looks like there is need for every domain also manually make record in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure truly does need to know the new CNAME. Otherwise it wouldn't know to route the traffic to your app.

The remaining question is whether or not it can be automated. I can't find the documentation for the management API for Web Sites, so I can't see whether or not this can be done programmatically. The command-line tools do *not* expose a method to do this.